# Remove duplicate nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

First of i am sorry to say that "removing duplicate node not working all the ways as expected" even i referred multiple threads which are helped to some extend but still i have not reached to the solution what i expected.

To brief my case I want to remove XitemSup complex type element if my supplier and origin_country_id is same in following descendant.

Below is the xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsd ns3"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ns3:XItemSupDesc>
         <xsl:for-each select="//ns3:XItemSupDesc/ns3:XitemSup">             
            <xsl:if test="not(ns3:supplier=following::ns3:supplier) or not(ns3:origin_country_id=following::ns3:origin_country_id)">
                   <ns3:XitemSup>
                     <ns3:supplier>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns3:supplier"/>
                     </ns3:supplier>
                     <ns3:primary_supp_ind>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns3:primary_supp_ind"/>
                     </ns3:primary_supp_ind>
                     <ns3:origin_country_id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns3:origin_country_id"/>
                     </ns3:origin_country_id>
                     <ns3:primary_country_ind>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns3:primary_country_ind"/>
                     </ns3:primary_country_ind>
                     <ns3:unit_cost>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./ns3:unit_cost"/>
                     </ns3:unit_cost>
                  </ns3:XitemSup>
               </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </ns3:XItemSupDesc>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if i apply on below xml it is not working

```
<XItemSupDesc xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier">
   <ns2:XitemSup>
      <ns2:supplier>101018</ns2:supplier>
      <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
      <ns2:origin_country_id>CA</ns2:origin_country_id>
      <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
      <ns2:unit_cost>6</ns2:unit_cost>
   </ns2:XitemSup>
   <ns2:XitemSup>
      <ns2:supplier>102825</ns2:supplier>
      <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
      <ns2:origin_country_id>IN</ns2:origin_country_id>
      <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
      <ns2:unit_cost>13</ns2:unit_cost>
   </ns2:XitemSup>
   <ns2:XitemSup>
      <ns2:supplier>102825</ns2:supplier>
      <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
      <ns2:origin_country_id>IN</ns2:origin_country_id>
      <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
      <ns2:unit_cost>24</ns2:unit_cost>
   </ns2:XitemSup>
</XItemSupDesc>
```

I am hoping someone can let me know where I am going wrong with XSLT code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using an `xsl:for-each` and just overriding the identity transform.

**XML Input**

```
<XItemSupDesc xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier">
    <ns2:XitemSup>
        <ns2:supplier>101018</ns2:supplier>
        <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
        <ns2:origin_country_id>CA</ns2:origin_country_id>
        <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
        <ns2:unit_cost>6</ns2:unit_cost>
    </ns2:XitemSup>
    <ns2:XitemSup>
        <ns2:supplier>102825</ns2:supplier>
        <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
        <ns2:origin_country_id>IN</ns2:origin_country_id>
        <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
        <ns2:unit_cost>13</ns2:unit_cost>
    </ns2:XitemSup>
    <ns2:XitemSup>
        <ns2:supplier>102825</ns2:supplier>
        <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
        <ns2:origin_country_id>IN</ns2:origin_country_id>
        <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
        <ns2:unit_cost>24</ns2:unit_cost>
    </ns2:XitemSup>
</XItemSupDesc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns2:XitemSup">
        <xsl:if test="not(following::ns2:XitemSup[ns2:supplier=current()/ns2:supplier and ns2:origin_country_id=current()/ns2:origin_country_id])">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<XItemSupDesc xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TSS_to_RMS/RIBXItemProcess/Supplier">
   <ns2:XitemSup>
      <ns2:supplier>101018</ns2:supplier>
      <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
      <ns2:origin_country_id>CA</ns2:origin_country_id>
      <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
      <ns2:unit_cost>6</ns2:unit_cost>
   </ns2:XitemSup>
   <ns2:XitemSup>
      <ns2:supplier>102825</ns2:supplier>
      <ns2:primary_supp_ind>N</ns2:primary_supp_ind>
      <ns2:origin_country_id>IN</ns2:origin_country_id>
      <ns2:primary_country_ind>N</ns2:primary_country_ind>
      <ns2:unit_cost>24</ns2:unit_cost>
   </ns2:XitemSup>
</XItemSupDesc>
```

Note: If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could get rid of the `xsl:if` and change the template to:

```
<xsl:template match="ns2:XitemSup[following::ns2:XitemSup[ns2:supplier=current()/ns2:supplier and ns2:origin_country_id=current()/ns2:origin_country_id]]"/>
```

Comment: ,Honestly your Awesome.. Your XSLT work like charm. Only thing i could get the result from xslt 2.0, but i used 1.0 which is giving desire result. First experience  with stackoverflow is impressed. Thanks a ton again.